# How to convert 0x (hex) into denary in C++

Tags: c++

I want my output to be a denary value instead of a hexadecimal value. Currently, when I try to output the code, It gives me the answer in 0x... and I want it to come out in denary instead. My output line is in the line: `wcout << pdMyDouble << endl;` How do I convert the output from hex to dec? Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double *child(void) {
    double *pdLocalVariable = new double;
    return pdLocalVariable;
}

void parent(void) {
    double* pdMyDouble = child();
    *pdMyDouble = 1.1;

    delete pdMyDouble;
    pdMyDouble = 0;
    wcout << pdMyDouble << endl;
}
```

Thanks for your help! ~sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: "Denary" is better known in English as "decimal", which may help your searching.

Comment: With `wcout << pdMyDouble` you output the *pointer*, not the value it's pointing to (which you can't since it no longer exist).

Comment: `wcout << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pdMyDouble) << endl;`

Comment: @Eljay I don't think the `reinterpret_cast` should be necessary here -- just `std::cout << std::uintptr_t(pdMyDouble) << std::endl`, right?

Comment: Minor point: for this question, `double *pdMyDouble = 0; wcout << pdMyDouble << endl;` is sufficient. The rest of the code doesn't affect the output.

Comment: @G.M. -- `std::uintptr_t(pdMyDouble)` is a C-style cast in function-cast form. It's the same sledgehammer as `(std::uintptr_t)pdMyDouble`. So, yes, you can write it that way, but `reinterpret_cast` is narrower and more visible.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but `wcout << std::dec << pdMyDouble << endl;` might work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the expected output from the code you show. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

When you use pointers and you want to print values of variable you must use this `cout<<*a;` when you using `cout<<a;` you print location of pointer. Not a value.

If you want convert hex to dec you can use this:

```
int k =0x265; //hex
std::cout<< std::hex << k; //use hex manipulator
```